# Lower case letters in @Table annotation causes error

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a problem with hibernate.
I get `must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key error` when it comes to `al_coursedetailed` table.
But it seems that this error is some kind of fake because when I change at least one of letters in `@Table` annotation to capital letter (e.g. `Al_coursedetailed`) everything is working fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the same operations on your databse servers? Some servers are case sensitive. Also showing some configuration of hibernate, showing some code and menitioning the database server with version will help folks around here to help you better!!

Comment: Table name in database server is all in lower case letters. When i do some SQL queries in some db client everything is ok - using lower case. Unfotunately it is hard to post some code in a nutshell because is quite complicated and spread. I have of course many more tables with similar configuration and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%lower_case%';
```

If the value of `lower_case_table_names` = 1, then, in the output of `SHOW TABLES`, you won't be able to see the table names in the original case in which they were created.

But we need to know which O/S you're on, which version of MySQL, and the output of the above `SHOW` statement to help further.

See also [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)